# MQ process amqrmppa get defunct status in Linux

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i've got a problem with process **`amqrmppa`** showing **`defunct`** status, please see detail as below:

```
mqm       2055  2912  0 Sep01 ?        00:00:31 [amqrmppa] <defunct>
mqm       2524  2912  0 Sep02 ?        00:00:23 [amqrmppa] <defunct>
mqm       2570  2912  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:21 [amqrmppa] <defunct>
mqm       4754  2912  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:19 [amqrmppa] <defunct>
mqm       5628  2912  0 Sep02 ?        00:00:23 [amqrmppa] <defunct>
```

i checked the error log file but got nothing clue there. can you help me figure it out? how to handle this?

Thanks

WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform) 
   7.0.1.5 
   Linux 2.6.32.12-0.7-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the channel pooling processes.  There are several reasons for this state, the most common of which being that channels were preemptively killed or that the parent process for these was killed.  Other less common errors include improperly coded channel exits or the occasional bug.  (Yes, amqrrmpa shows up in the APAR list from time to time.)  It is really difficult to provide any more specific response than this without seeing the channel configurations.  If it is not possible to post them for security reasons, you'll need to open a PMR and let IBM look at them.  Specifically, I'd be looking to see whether the channels run in FASTPATH or trusted mode, whether exits are defined, etc.  I'd also look at the version and fix pack level, then look at the APAR list for the later fixes to see if any address the problem.  If these do not point to potential issues, then it's time to run through the [MustGather](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg21229861) procedure and open a PMR.

For what its worth, it is usually a good idea to go to the MustGather page and drill down by platform and problem category to get some really helpful diagnostic advice.